# using find command in linux for filenames generated from previous command

Tags: linux, awk, find, cut

I am trying to use `find` command like this

```
cut -f 4 file.txt | awk 'NR>1' | find ./ -name
```

After the awk command my input looks like this

```
foo.c
foo.txt
abc.txt
```

How can I feed the name of the file coming from previous command to find command?
So basically looking for `foo.c` and getting it's path, then `foo.txt` and getting its path and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it may be easier to get `find` to find every file and `awk` to select the ones with the names you want. For instance, assuming a `awk` that supports setting the record separator to NUL:

```bash
find . -print0 | awk '
  ! names_loaded {if (NR>1) names[$4]; next}
  $NF in names' FS='\t' file.txt names_loaded=1 FS=/ RS='\0' -
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separately add a bunch of options for each `-name`. Try this:

```
IFS='
'
set -o noglob
find . -false $(awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\n' '
    NR>1 && $4 != "" { print "-o", "-name", $4}' file.txt)
```

`awk` prints the arguments one per line and we use the split+glob operator (`$(...)` unquoted) in the shell, with the *glob* part disabled and the *split* part tuned to split on newline only to pass those as arguments to `find`.

This could fail if `file.txt` is large. Also beware names are treated as patterns. For instance, if there's a line containing `[f]ile*`, it will find all files whose name starts with `file`, not the file called `[f]ile*`.

The normal [and safe](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#backticks) arrangement would be to use `xargs`:

```
something something | xargs -r0 find . -false
```

but `xargs` could run `find` multiple times and split the argument list between an `-o` and a `-name` or between `-name` and the actual file name. We could avoid that by passing `-n 150` or any number that is a multiple of 3 and is hoped to be small enough to fit in the limit  of the size of arguments.

Putting `-false` first simplifies the rest of the processing because that way, we can make the output completely regular, with an `-o` before each `-name`.

If your `find` doesn't support that non-standard predicate, you could replace it with `-links 0` or anything guaranteed to be false.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zsh` recursive globs here instead of `find` which make it easier:

```
filenames=( ${(f)"$(<file.txt tail -n +2 | cut -f 4)"} )
print -rC1 -- **/(${(~j[|])filenames})(ND)
```

Were we use the `f` *parameter expansion flag* to split the output of `cut` on line-`f`eeds and use `~j[|]` to join the array members with the `|` alternation glob operator, `**/` for any number of subdirs, `D` for dotglob, `N` for nullglob.

Matches are `print`ed `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn.

If the names are meant to be interpreted as patterns instead of file names, you can change it to:

```
print -rC1 -- **/(${(j[|])~filenames})(ND)
```

Where `~` for globsubst here applies to the whole expansion, not just the `|` introduced by the `j`oin flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would have `find` send its whole output to `awk`, and search for the required names using a hash table. Basically, like:

```
Awk='
#.. Extract required names from list.
FS == " " { if (FNR > 1) Name[$4]; next; }
#.. List paths for given names.
$(NF) in Name { print; }
'
find . -type f -print0 | awk "${Awk}" FS=' ' "file.txt" RS=$'\0' FS='/' - | sort
```

The sort gathers the output by name (there may be duplicates within the directory tree).

A refinement might be to count hits in the `Name[]` array, and list the names that had no hits in an END block.

Note that the `find` output is null-terminated (`-print0` in find, `RS` as `NUL` in awk), and only files are referenced (having a directory accidentally match a supplied name is an issue with other solutions).